# How to add `codec/std` as a std feature to the substrate-node-template?

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/) and when I add this code to my untime/Cargo.toml

```
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
  "codec/std",
  "scale-info/std",
  "frame-executive/std",
  "frame-support/std",
  "frame-system-rpc-runtime-api/std",
  "frame-system/std",
  "pallet-aura/std",
  "pallet-balances/std",
  "pallet-contracts/std",
  "pallet-contracts-primitives/std",
]
```

but when I test it out with `cargo check -p node-template-runtime` I get this error:

```
error: failed to load manifest for workspace member `/home/bosr/rust/substrate-node-template/node`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/home/bosr/rust/substrate-node-template/node/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `std` includes `codec/std`, but `codec` is not a dependency
```

What is the name of the dependency I need to add to make it work?  I tried `codec` but the compiler tells me `error: no matching package named` codec `found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `codec` dependency exists, if you doesn't find it you can use this
`codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a Rust question.

If you want to enable some features of a crate. Apparently, you must ensure you have that crate already.

---

```
# you need to add x first
#
# usually, people enable std feature by default
# so, you probably need to disable the default-features here 
x = { version = "0.1.0", default-features = false }

[features]
# then enable the std here
std = ["x/std"]
```

Comment: `codec =` is an alias name. The real name is `parity-scale-codec`. I recommend you learn some Rust first. There is no "correct" format. Just because we use an alias name here. You could also write `parity-scale-codec = { version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }`

Comment: IMHO, that answer is not good. He didn't tell you why you need to write in this way. Anyway, have some Rust first.  :)